# How can I stop the interstital ad sound after closing an ad?

Tags: flutter, admob

After closing an ad, the sound of an interstital ad video does not stop. How can I stop this sound?

Here it is my code block:

```
    InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: adUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          interstitialAd = ad as InterstitialAd?;
          if (showAfterLoad) showInterstitialAd();
          interstitialAd!.dispose();
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          print('Failed to load ad: $error');

          interstitialAd = null; // Eğer reklam yüklenemezse null yap
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showInterstitialAd() async {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
      return Future(() => interstitialAd!.show());
    }
  }
```

I have called ads like that:

```
  final FirebaseService firebaseService = FirebaseService();
  FavoriteServices favoriteServices = Get.put(FavoriteServices());
  final GoogleAds googleAds = GoogleAds();
  Timer? _refreshTimer;
  Map<String, List<News>> newsDataMap = {
    'sonDakika': [],
    'dunya': [],
    'spor': [],
    'magazin': [],
  };

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //firebaseService.startTimer(); // Tüm kategoriler için timer'ı başlat.
    googleAds.loadBannerAd(adLoaded: () {
      setState(() {});
    });
    googleAds.loadInterstitalAd();
    _startRefreshTimer(); // Yenileme timer'ını başlat.
  }
```

I tried to use the onAdClosed method of InterstitialAd.load(), but there isn't any such method.

Comment: What is *"interstital ad video"*?

Comment: [OK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstitial_webpage), *"On the web, an interstitial webpage (or interstitial) is a web page displayed before or after an expected content page, often to display advertising or for regulatory reasons, such as to confirm the user's age (prior to showing age-restricted material) or obtain consent to store cookies. Most interstitial advertisements are delivered by an ad server."*